# Select only 1 row after ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to get only 1 row after ordering? I don't want to load DB so much, so I want to get only 1 row (it may be from the middle), here is an example:

| ID | User | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | 10 |
| 2 | user2 | 60 |
| 3 | user3 | 45 |

I want to get the fe. the second user after `` ORDER BY `points` DESC ``, so the table will look like

| ID | User | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | user2 | 60 |
| 3 | user3 | 45 |
| 1 | user1 | 10 |

The second user is `user3`, and I want to return just that one row. It is possible? Or do I need to get all and just `LIMIT` it?

Comment: Like using `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: What if there were two+ users with 45 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strictly get only one row, corresponding to the second highest points, then my guess is that on ties you want the lowest id. In that case you can use the `LIMIT` function accordingly.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
ORDER BY points DESC, 
         ID
LIMIT 1,1
```

The so written `LIMIT` clause will allow you to start limiting from the second row, then takes the first row available (which is the second one).

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ii6qZvRvGajNP92dBMncfE/0).

Comment: is it the same as LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1? I have found the solution now

Comment: Yeah, this version omits the keyword `OFFSET`. @PoLeq

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySql 8+ you can use *rank*, for example:

```
with r as (
    select * , Rank() over(order by points desc) rnk
    from t
)
select id, user, points
from r
where rnk = 2;
```